# if $G$ is a simple planar graph, $\chi(G) \geq 4 \Rightarrow G$ contains a cycle of length $\leq 5$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

In one of the questions of my practice exam, there is a question that asks to show that if $G$ is a simple planar graph that contains no cycle of length 5 or less, then $\chi(G) \leq 3$.
The solution given to us (included at the end) is a proof by induction on the statement, but intuitively this is not how I would have approached the problem.

My first thought was to prove the contrapositive: $\chi(G)\geq 4 \Rightarrow G$ contains a cycle of length $\leq 5$.
I was initially thinking of using induction (on vertices or edges) to show the contrapositive.
The base case ($K_4$, either $|V|=4$ or $|E|=6$) contains a cycle of length 4.
For the induction step, if we consider any vertex (or perhaps edge?) and let $G'=G[V-v]$ for some vertex $v$, then there are 2 cases. Either $\chi(G')=4$, and by induction hypothesis we are done. Otherwise, $\chi(G')=3$, but I am struggling to find the right argument here. Does anyone have an idea about how I could approach this case? Clearly in that case $v$ is incident to 3 colors in $G'$, and so I was thinking of coming up with a cycle alternating between vertices of different colors.

The other idea I had was to use the fact (already proven in my notes) that if $G$ does not contain a $K_4$ minor, then $\chi(G) \leq 3$. The contrapositive of this gives us that if $\chi(G) \geq 4$, then $G$ contains a $K_4$ minor.
In the statement I need to prove, $G$ is planar, so it does not contain a $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ minor/subdivision by Kuratowski's theorem. I was therefore thinking of using a proof by contradiction (assuming $G$ had no cycle of length $\leq 5$ and $\chi(G) \geq 4$, and then using the fact that $G$ contains a $K_4$ minor but no $K_5$ minor  to show that $G$ has a cycle of length $\leq 5$ which is a contradiction). however, once again I am not exactly sure how to show this contradiction.

Could someone please help me prove the statement using one of these approaches (proving the contrapositive instead of the main statement, or proving the main statement by contradiction)? Thanks.

Here is the main proof:
[proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRJla.png)

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood something but it seems that you finished your proof. I mean you have proven that $\chi(G) \ge 4$ gives us that $G$ contains a copy of $K_4$. But then trivially $K_4$ has a cycle of length $\le 5$

Comment: @Stefan4024 $G$ does not contain a copy of $K_4$, it contains $K_4$ as a minor. This means that from a subgraph $H$ of $G$, it is possible to apply some edge contractions and obtain $K_4$ (for instance, combine edge $\{a,b\}$ and $\{b,c\}$ to get $\{a,c\}$, and make all edges other edges that had $b$ has endpoint incident to $a$).